Hiding Script on Mobile
I am using widgetbot on my forum, but the icon covers up important information on mobile. Is there a way to hide this only on mobile? The script has been added into the header via admin panel.
I have tried using CSS and the below codes.
Also, something to note: I am using Flarum forum software and do not have a viable way to edit root files without the edit being replaced in the updates.
Original:
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@widgetbot/crate@3' async defer>
    new Crate({
        server: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // DISCORD
        channel: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' // ⁠general
    })
 button.notify({
      content: 'Background updated',
      timeout: 1000
    })


</script>

My attempt that didn't work:
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@widgetbot/crate@3' async defer>
function includeHTML() {
  if (mobilecheck()) {
      return;
  }
    new Crate({
        server: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // DISCORD
        channel: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' // ⁠general
    })
 button.notify({
      content: 'Background updated',
      timeout: 1000
    })
</script>


Figured it out. Incase anyone wants to know for their own use.


<script>
    function isMobileDevice() {
        return (typeof window.orientation !== "undefined") || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('IEMobile') !== -1);
    }
    if (!isMobileDevice()) {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@widgetbot/crate@3';
        script.async = true;
        script.defer = true;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        script.onload = function() {
            new Crate({
                server: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX', // DISCORD
                channel: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' // ⁠general
            });
            button.notify({
                content: 'Background updated',
                timeout: 1000
            });
        };
    }
</script>



